# Ionic android build generate unsigned apk, but donot install in my android 8.1.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

when i serve ionic app, its working in browser but the build apk for android not working. the apk is not installable.

i tried ionic cordova build android --release

the build pass with following message

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ruban\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE`
```

```
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
```

The build creates unsigned apk file which doesnot install on my android device.

Ionic info command shows follwing messages
Ionic:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\ruban\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1
```

Cordova:

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)
```

System:

```
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\ruban\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: have you tried without --release flag

Comment: without --release it didnot  throw any error, but the apk is still not installable

Comment: whenever i try to install it, it shows "app not installed"

Comment: could you tell me what is the argument --release for

Comment: IT worked build without --release worked, but could you tell me importance of --release

Comment: --release flag is used to publish to playstore. you can't install with release flag unitil singed and alized apk.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to fix anything couse it isn't an error.
but if you want to fix it...

if you don't like this alert,
you should add the next lines to the config.xml file

```
<splash density="ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-mdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
```

the resources can be drawable-xxxhdpi-screen ... or u can use port or land.

with the next line you should be able to generate the key to sign it

keytool -genkey -v -keystore ejemplo.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

and with the next line you will be able to sign your app

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ejemplo.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

With this you sign the apk and you will be able to install the app in Android.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't generate the [resources](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources) yet. Try out the following:

```
ionic cordova resources
```

Comment: apk could not install, however it runs on webview, when i do ionic serve

Comment: Try to run it on the device to see what's the error.

Comment: ionic cordova run android

Comment: when doing ionic cordova run android

```BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ruban\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
Using apk: D:\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Package name: io.ionic.starter
INSTALL SUCCESS
LAUNCH SUCCESS```

Comment: Ok, then no problem at all. What you're doing is that you're trying to install a release apk which is unsigned which is not accepted.

Comment: it runs on emulator, but the build doesnot

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `ANDROID_HOME`to your `PATH`

> set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools 
>   set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Comment: do i have to set 
```set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools 

or

set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk```

Answer (score 0):

Simple run application in android :

1) Connect device and make sure enable usb debugging (in setting - developer options)

2) In cmd type : adb devices

3) Now run : ionic cordova run android

(Ionic cli will do everything and install in your device.)